# Trouble with "Thread creation failed (err=Try again, stacksize=1016KB)"

Tags: android, memory-management, fragment

I have a serious trouble with my Android app.

My project is a fragment-based project.

When I tap on a certain button which shows a fragment then it shows that fragment without problem.

"taps on back-button, and then taps on "show-fragment" button again."

If I repeated these steps rapidly, then the following error was displayed on log-cat and the app was crashed.

> 08-21 19:37:23.557: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try
>   again, stacksize=1016KB) 08-21 19:37:23.557: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread
>   creation failed (err=Try again, stacksize=984KB) 08-21 19:37:23.558:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=952KB) 08-21 19:37:23.558: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=920KB) 08-21 19:37:23.558:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=1016KB) 08-21 19:37:23.558: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread
>   creation failed (err=Try again, stacksize=984KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=952KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=920KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=888KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=856KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=824KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=792KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=760KB) 08-21 19:37:23.559: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=728KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=696KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=664KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=632KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=600KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=568KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=536KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=504KB) 08-21 19:37:23.560: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=472KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=440KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=408KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=376KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=344KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=312KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=280KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=248KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=216KB) 08-21 19:37:23.561:
>   E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation failed (err=Try again,
>   stacksize=184KB) 08-21 19:37:23.562: E/dalvikvm(4975): Thread creation
>   failed (err=Try again, stacksize=152KB) 08-21 19:37:23.876:
>   A/libc(4975): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread
>   4975 (oman.tasklogger) 08-21 19:37:23.876: A/libc(4975): Send stop
>   signal to pid:4975 in void debuggerd_signal_handler(int, siginfo_t*,
>   void*)

I think there maybe an memory issue in my project configuration.
Anyone who have an experience such this error should help me.
The same error occurred when I repeat showing alert dialog and pressing back-button several times.

Is this an out of memory problem?

Here is my code for showing alert dialog.

```
public class ReportFragment extends BaseFragment {
....

private void onShowAlertButtonClicked() {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     builder.setTitle("Fruits");
     builder.setItems(new String[]{"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}, null);
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
}

...
}
```

In a word, when this onShowAlertButtonClicked callback is triggered several times, then the app crashes.
I have seen stack-overflow which described about `AlertDialog` in Fragment.
They said that context is important for `AlertDialog`.
So I have changed the alert dialog's context with various context such as Activity and Application,
but the error was still.

Perhaps this error is not hard for Android ninja.

Thanks for viewing my report.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
private void onShowAlertButtonClicked(View v) {
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
     builder.setTitle("Fruits");
     builder.setItems(new String[]{"Apple", "Orange", "Banana"}, null);
     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your notice. I've fixed the error by removing idle loop code snippet. Then my question is what happens when I use v.getContext() instead of getActivity().